# Insert String Value To Binary(64) Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, varbinary

I am attempting to use a stored procedure to insert data into a table.  The DDL of my table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [company] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [pass] [binary](64) NOT NULL,
    [registrationdate] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[data1] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data1] ([ID], [fname], [lname], [phone], [company], [email], [pass], [registrationdate]) VALUES (1, N'Bob', N'Tomato', N'5555555555', N'Test Company', N'test1234@test.com', 0x477265656E0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[data1] OFF
GO
```

And this is the stored procedure that I am attempting to execute:

```
Declare @FName varchar(100) = 'aa'
Declare @Lname varchar(100) = 'bb'
Declare @Phone varchar(100) = 'cc'
Declare @Company varchar(100) = 'dd'
Declare @Email varchar(100) = 'ee'
Declare @Pass binary(64) = 'redsocks'


INSERT INTO dbo.appinfo (fname, lname, phone, company, email, pass) 
VALUES (@FName, @Lname, @Phone, @Company, @Email, CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), @Pass, 0))
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 20
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Is this statement not converting the value appropriately?

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), @Pass, 0))
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - that got it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the convert in the declare line, not during the insert. The error happens on the declare line, so the insert is never reached.